# Is it possible to tell the label that the text should be labeled?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I need to add all the text that comes to the label a `strikethrough.`

In html this is done with `<s> </s>` tags. And how to do it in the swift?

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKUgS.png)

Comment: You mean you need to add a default text to a label right.?

Comment: i added image, sorry

Comment: Added the answer. lemme know if it helps you.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this code:

```
 let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your Text")
 attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
 self.label.attributedText = attributeString
```

Output:

[image]

Hope this helps.

### Edit according to your code

As per your code you want to show that in the Tableview label

So you can use it like,

add this lines in `cellForRowAt`

```
let strText = schedule[indexPath.row].discipline
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: strText) // Get here the text you want to show in your label
attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
cell.dispos.attributedText = attributeString
```

And it will work!

### Edit Not working in real Device

Possibly you have not ticked the `Target Membership` of any of the files which you are using. Make sure it is ticked , if not then tick it and it will work perfectly.

[image]

Comment: how i use your code from my code?
https://github.com/golub1/timetable_1/blob/master/ZameniYGK/ViewController.swift
i have tableview and array

Comment: @SergeyVerigin Can i know where you want to show this strikeTrough.? in your code.? I can edit it there for you. I have seen you have taken a label named groupn. But in what case you want to show that.?

Comment: I corrected the code for the git. I would like to see that this data is displayed in a strikethrough format
   cell.dispos.text = schedule[indexPath.row].discipline

Comment: Edited the answer For you, assuming that cell.dispos is label in tableViewCell

Comment: Pleasure helping you buddy.

Comment: Have you used custom fonts.? Or any thing which you have imported from outside xcode.?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it as default for a label, create a subclass of the UILabel.

Let's call the subclass MyLabel, so in MyLabel.swift

```
class MyLabel: UILabel {
    override internal var text: String? {
        didSet {
            if let text = self.text {
                let attribString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)  
                attribString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle,
                                          value: 2,
                                          range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attribString.length))
                self.attributedText = attribString
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Then in your StoryBoard file or Xib File, assign the class name:
[image: ASSIGNING CLASS TO LABEL IN XIB FILE]

This will make sure that all text in the label are strikethrough by default

Comment: Now when you take the outlet, The outlet will by default have the class name as MyLabel

Answer (score 0):

```
    private func getStrikeThroughTextFor(_ text:String) -> 
    NSMutableAttributedString {
      let attributeString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
      let attributes : [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.baselineOffset:0,
                                                     .strikethroughStyle:2]
      attributeString.addAttributes(attributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, 
        attributeString.length))
      return attributeString
  }
```